# How to check if someone is a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm designing a website (ASP.NET, c#), in which you can see the controls, but you can only use them after you've logged in (for example, you can see a list of games, but you can only place a bet after you've logged in, so if you try to place a bet when you are not logged in, the site should redirect you to the login page).

All said, my problem is this: How can you tell, if a certain user is logged in, BEFORE he types in his credentials?

He his not a user yet right? For me he is just someone that is browsing my website.

Comment: right. You may want to look into how Forms authentication works in ASP.NET along with the authentication cookie.

Comment: As soon some one one login/enter credentials, you can create session and check if session exist show/hide controls

Answer (score 1):

If the user is logged in then `Request.IsAuthenticated` is `true`.  When the request is authenticated, the `User.Identity.Name` property is set to the user's username.  Before the user is authenticated there is no way to tell who the user is.  You can, via some javascript code, find out what that person types into your Username textbox, but until the password is validated, you can't be sure it is that user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to research cookies and query the database based on cookie settings.

Comment: You really should add more information to your answer.  ASP.NET already has a pretty comprehensive authentication/authorization/roles plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has not logged into your site ever before, there is no way to tell whether he/she is a a user. The most widely used authentication mechanism for ASP.NET is [Forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) which returns an authentication cookie to the user's browser which subsequently accompanies all requests by that user so it can be used to track who that user is and that he is authenticated for the current session (also see ["Understanding the Forms Authentication Ticket and Cookie"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443)).

You could use a separate, long lived cookie to just identify the user's name which then would be (usually) also available after the user has logged out. When that person visits your site you can at least use the name to remind him/her to log in.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses :)
BrokenGlass, unfortunetly, I don't quite sure I understand. You wrote: "If someone has not logged into your site ever before, there is no way to tell whether he/she is a a user." - but that's execly what I need.. I need to be able to identify that someone is not logged in. There must be some way to do it no? maybe my entire approch is wrong to begin with..?